# How to set case_insensitive for term query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch term query documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html, it is stated there's a `case_insensitive` field

However, I can't get to set it. I can set `boost` and `value` without issue, but not `case_insensitive`.

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "overview": {
        "value" : "batman",
        "boost": 0.5,
        "case-insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run, I get the error state `"[term] query does not support [case_insensitive]"`.

Where did I get it wrong, or the documentation is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are on less than the ES 7.10.0 version where it was not present, Even if you check the [documentation of ES 7.9](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/query-dsl-term-query.html) option of `case_insensitive` is not present.

Please find the related link of [Github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/53603) and [PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/63218/files) which added support of case-insensitive to term query.

Please refer to [this diff](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/63218/files#diff-af467c40539932604182b32678b7236edf6cfbb0b0fa1b9a2c2377b4a1e917f7R20) where `caseInsensitive` field was added to TermQuery.

Comment: Nice one. After upgrade to version 7.11.0, now it works!